# Table in Access Is Now Read Only

Tags: ms-access

I'm restructuring a database for a customer, in the back end I have set a column to allow duplicates in the "items" table and now the front end database is saying  that the data is read only.

Comment: How are you looking at it on the FE? Are you looking at the actual table or  form which displays it?

Comment: In a form. We also tried from the query. If I set it back to "No duplicates" everything goes back to normal and data can be deleted once a gain from the FE... The person who designed this DB passed away and I inherited it. So im lost

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the simplest explanation. Is the cell locked?

Access>Your form>Design View>Form Properties

[image]

Second Simplest, switch the combo box at the top of the picture to "Form". Then check if any of these field look off.

[image]

Comment: Is that there for all access versions? I'm testing on a 2010 version and the actually version is 2000. I don't see the lock option on my 2010 test side. I've right clicked the window and clicked properties.

Comment: Try selecting the field then checking properties again. But, it may be a feature that wasn't there before and so didn't carry over.

Comment: I table isnt read only cause I can open on the FE and make changes. Is the query read only? I have no clue what is going on

Comment: Right. In the FE, you want to open the form in design view, then select that misbehaving field, right click, field properties, see if it's locked.

Comment: I don't think there is a miss behaving field. The form is displaying info from a query that gets info from 3 tables. I can open those 3 tables and edit info from the FE, but the query tells me "read only".. PS The field Is not locked

Comment: All those options were set to allow edits. It was a recordset option, I finally fixed it. Thanks for helping though

Answer (score 0):

[image]

STRIKE Fixed, Just make sure the the source where the data in the form is coming from, has this option set. STRIKE

DONT USE THIS

Comment: I feel like a idiot, somehow in someway this is not a good setting to turn on. Deleting data from the form actually deleted important information from the table and I ended up looking like a idiot when testing on the clients computer.